# Practical Applications / Uses of DES algorithm

Tags: encryption, cryptography, des

I am new to Cryptography and studying the concepts for the very first time. Accept my apology for the very basic question

Can someone please give me some uses/application or implementations of DES Algorithm that (where its been used) or (where it was used)?

Comment: Wherever not-so-strong encryption is needed. The range of what encryption is generally used is vast and DES is sadly still used today (Look at all the new DES questions here on Stack Overflow). This question cannot be answered in any way.

Comment: DES, like any block cipher, can be used in a random number generator or as a permutation generator.

Comment: Thanks @ArtjomB. for giving some clues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only current practical use of DES is as a building block to get to three-key Triple DES for a legacy system.

"Where it was used" was decades ago for all kinds of encryption - at the time, it was used much like AES, Aria, and Camellia are today, as a modern cipher considered to be strong.

Comment: Thanks for your elaboration. But I wonder where are those people who actually down voted for the question.